# Using binary search to find the index of an item in a sequence

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, reinventing-the-wheel, binary-search

Here's my script:

```
def index(seq, item):
    """Returns the index of an item in an increasingly-sorted
       sequence (if exists) otherwise returns the index where
       it would be inserted, using binary search.

       seq: a sequence.

       precondition: seq is sorted increasingly.
       """
    # Updates the sequence with the item using a
    # set to avoid duplicates.
    seq = set(seq)
    seq.update([item])

    # Converts the sequence to a list and re-sorts it. 
    sorted_seq = sorted(seq)

    middle = len(sorted_seq) // 2
    middle_value = sorted_seq[middle]

    first_half = sorted_seq[:middle]
    second_half = sorted_seq[middle:]

    if item == middle_value:
        return middle

    elif item < middle_value:
        return index(first_half, item)

    elif item > middle_value:
        return index(second_half, item) + len(first_half)
```

How can it be refactored and optimized?

Notes:

- I'm a hobbyist and beginner (in programming in general, and **Python** in particular).
- I'm new to ***binary search*** I just understand the basic idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
seq = set(seq)
seq.update([item])

# Converts the sequence to a list and re-sorts it. 
sorted_seq = sorted(seq)
```

In worst case, **`sorted()`** will take \$\Theta(n \log n)\$, where \$n = \$ **`len(seq)`**. Even worse, if you did not found the value, you recur to half of the original sequence, and so on.

So, instead of presorting the sequence, just proceed to doing the actual search; if the caller fails to input a sorted list, it's not your fault.

I have this in mind, runs in worst case logarithmic time and behaves exactly as your implementation:

```
def binary_search(lst, value):
    count = len(lst)
    first = 0

    while count:
        it = first
        step = count // 2
        it += step
        if value > lst[it]:
            it += 1
            first = it
            count -= step + 1
        else:
            count = step

    return first


def main():
    lst = [1, 2, 5, 10, 11, 17, 20]

    for value in range(0, 25):
        print("OP:", index(lst, value))
        print("cr:", binary_search(lst, value))
        print("---")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: if the caller fails to input a sorted list (...)

Just remember to rename parameter "seq" to "sorted_seq" or something to make it apparent to caller that the list should be presorted.

Answer (score 3):

```
seq = set(seq)
```

This will cause index calculations to be incorrect. Consider this invocation:

```
index([1, 1, 2, 3], 2)
```

This should return 2 but your function returns 1. As a caller of your `index` method, I would expect the returned index to have `item` in `seq`.

---

<s>seq.update([item])</s>

This is a bug. It's causing `print(index([1, 1, 2, 3], 15))` to return 3, when it should return `-1` or some other sentinel value to denote absence of an `item` in `seq`.

EDIT: The function's documentation clearly says that `index` will return the final index after insertion if `item` does not exist in `seq`.

---

```
sorted_seq = sorted(seq)
```

This is unnecessary. Validate/assume your input `seq` to be sorted. This should be the standard expectation from any caller invoking your `index` function.

---

Be careful about:

```
first_half = sorted_seq[:middle]
second_half = sorted_seq[middle:]
```

Python fortunately will not create copies of the list but other languages may create copies of the original list for this operation.

---

After you have removed `seq.update([item])`, you will need to check for the base of your recursion, namely when `seq` is empty, causing

```
middle_value = sorted_seq[middle]
```

to fail.

---

As an aside, try implementing this as an iterative algorithm.

1. It will run faster
2. The recursive version will crash for large `seq`.

Totally aside, have a look at [Binary Search tutorial on TopCoder](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/binary-search/) Its a pretty good article.

Comment: Thank you! I've stated in the docstring  **otherwise returns the index where it would be inserted**, theerfore I've used `seq.update([item])`. But Using `seq = set(seq)` is buggy as you've mentioned. Can you explain, please, what you mean by **Python fortunately will not create copies of the list but other languages may create copies of the original list for this operation.**, ?

Comment: @MahmudMuhammadNaguib I was pointing at the memory requirements of your algorithm. In each recursive step of your algorithm, you probably do not want to create fresh copies of the first and second halves of the arrays. Python slices do this by default but in a language other than python, you would probably want to pass the list by reference along with `high`/`end` and `low`/`start` pointers/indexes that mark the boundaries of the sequence to be searched for. This would incur the cost of 3 pointers in each recursive step, making extra memory requirements O(1).

Comment: Thanks! I suggest you remove `sorted_seq = sorted(seq)` and the section about it. After inserting `item` the sequence won't be sorted anymore, so we have to re-sort it.

Comment: Please do not do that. As the accepted answer suggests, that would make the time complexity O(n lg n). Beats the point of binary search, which is supposed to run in O(lg n). Instead this should be your binary search criteria: "Find the index of the leftmost element in seq which is >= item". This will take care of duplicates and missing elements.